# Placing an image in the transparent area of another image android

Tags: android, image, imageview, transparent

I am trying to replace the transparent area of a Frame Image with another image and I only want to replace that transparent area with my other image.
This is what I do for getting the transparent pixels from the bitmap of the frame and storing it. But it's not working.

```
 for (int x = 0; x < imgBitmap.getWidth(); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < imgBitmap.getHeight(); y++)
        {
            if (imgBitmap.getPixel(x, y) == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            {
                bottomX[i] = x;
                bottomY[i] = y;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Below is the transparent frame I am using.
[image: Transparent Frame image]

As I mentioned above I want to fill the transparent area with another image?
Any help or guide will be appreciated Thanks!

Comment: When you say it's not working, what is not working? The image has transparent pixels. Are you not finding them or are you unable to place the other image over this image. What is `i`?

Comment: I need some help to better understand the question, do you want to put an image inside your apple?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a custom view, which does 3 things:

1. Combine the mask with a background
2. Draws the result to a canvas
3. Draw the original mask again for nice shadows

```
class TransparentImageView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : AppCompatImageView(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {


    private val background: Bitmap
    private val mask: Bitmap
    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG)
    private val modeIn = PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN)

    init {
        context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.TransparentImageView, 0, 0).apply {
            background = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, getResourceId(R.styleable.TransparentImageView_bg, -1))
            mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, getResourceId(R.styleable.TransparentImageView_mask, -1))
            recycle()
        }
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

        val result = combine()
        canvas?.drawBitmap(result, 0f, 0f, null)

        // Draw the Masked image on top for shadows
        canvas?.drawBitmap(mask, 0f, 0f, null)
    }

    private fun combine(): Bitmap {
        val result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.width, mask.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        val tempCanvas = Canvas(result)
        paint.xfermode = modeIn
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(background, 0f, 0f, null)
        tempCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0f, 0f, paint)
        paint.xfermode = null
        return result
    }
}
```

here, I use custom attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="TransparentImageView">
        <attr name="mask" format="reference" />
        <attr name="bg" format="reference" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And you can use this like so:

```
 <my.custom.TransparentImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:bg="@drawable/background"
        app:mask="@drawable/mask"/>
```

This only works, when your masked image is a png

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace only the transparent x,y pixels with the corresponding x,y pixels of another image you can do something like the below. The first argument is your transparent image bitmap, the second argument is the other image bitmap and the 3rd argument is a boolean flag to replace pixels only for the transparent area. And Of course, you need to have both images of the same width and height to get the correct corresponding x,y pixels values from the other image.

```
 public static void combineBitmaps(Bitmap transBitmap, Bitmap otherBitmap, boolean replaceTransparentAreaOnly){

    try
    {
        Bitmap outputBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(transBitmap.getWidth(), transBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        for (int x = 0; x < transBitmap.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < transBitmap.getHeight(); y++) {
                int rgba = transBitmap.getPixel(x, y);
                int red = Color.red(rgba);
                int blue = Color.blue(rgba);
                int green = Color.green(rgba);
                int alpha = Color.alpha(rgba);

                //replace only transparent area
                if(replaceTransparentAreaOnly)
                {
                    //transparent pixel found, replace it with the corresponding x,y pixel of the other image
                    if (rgba == Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        outputBitmap.setPixel(x, y, otherBitmap.getPixel(x, y));
                    }
                    //otherwise set x,y pixel based on transparent image RGB colour
                    else {
                        outputBitmap.setPixel(x, y, Color.rgb(red, green, blue));
                    }
                }
                //replace non-transparent area
                else
                {
                    //non-transparent pixel found, replace it with the corresponding x,y pixel of the other image
                    if (rgba != Color.TRANSPARENT) {
                        outputBitmap.setPixel(x, y, otherBitmap.getPixel(x, y));
                    }
                    //otherwise set x,y pixel based on transparent image RGB colour
                    else {
                        outputBitmap.setPixel(x, y, rgba);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        //save the new outputBitmap here
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
```

and you can call this helper function like below:

```
 Bitmap appleBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.apple);
 Bitmap androidBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.other_image);
 combineBitmaps(appleBitmap, androidBitmap, true);
```

And the result after replacing the transparent-only areas of Apple image with the other (Android image) will be like below:

[image: apple1]
[image: other_image1]
[image: result1]

and in case you want to replace the non-transparent areas (White pixels) of the apple image the result will be like below:

[image: apple2]
[image: other_image2]
[image: result2]